# Python, uWSGI, NGINX, FLASK works on WiFi does not over cellular

Tags: python, nginx, mobile, flask, cellular-network

I'm using a Digital Ocean server to run a [personal website](https://njw.fish). The site works perfectly and I'm happy with it. I was able to get Lets Encrypt set up and working too (this problem existed before setting up Lets Encrypt).

Over WiFi. Over a cellular network the site doesn't load. But if I switch my phone to WiFi, it works fine. I have literally no idea what is causing this issue.

My set up is very standard, Python and flask, served by nginx and uWSGI. Everything was set up using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial. I am happy to post nginx config, uwsgi config, etc, and all source for the site is [here](https://github.com/njwfish/personal-site).

**UPDATE**

This issue is caused by a bug in certbot, which [doesn't handle IPV6 when used on NGINX](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4992). This can be fixed by editing the NGINX config and adding the lines in [Wander Nauta's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47981818/3846493)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'doesn't load'? Does your browser show an error message? Just an empty page?

Comment: "Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server."

And that's all I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address:

```
$ dig +short A njw.fish
138.197.30.136

$ dig +short AAAA njw.fish
2604:a880:800:10::20c1:d001
```

This is great, but it seems nginx is only listening on the IPv4 address. Instruct it to listen on both:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl;  # For IPv6
listen 443 ssl;       # For IPv4
```

Likely, your cell phone uses the (newer) IPv6, while your WiFi uses the (older) IPv4.